# Как выполнять поиск по topic в своих репозиториях github?

Tags: github

Есть ли у `github` функция поиска по **Topics**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу упорядочить свои репозитории по таким "тегам" что бы быстро искать нужные примеры из своего кода, но поиск по репозиториям учитывает только их названия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли такой-же способ по **Topics** выполнять поиск в рамках своего аккаунта?

Если его не существует, то буду признателен за советы кто как эту проблему решает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте к строке поиска [user:<имя юзера>](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/about-searching-on-github), например:

```
user:gil9red topic:fun
```